# read and write files to different directories Python

Tags: python-2.7, file-io

I want my code to go into a sub directory, perform some operation and save the output in a file which is one step up, to the main dir.

Main directory ---> sub_directory

I would appreciate solutions which do not require "hardcoding" the path of the main 
directory. Is there a way I can directly write my file output to the main dir without
doing a os.chdir() every iteration? Something like just giving the path of the file to read and write?

For eg:

```
# example
import os

for i in xrange(10):
    code to read and operate on some file in this sub dir one by one (ten files)
    # write output file to the previous directory
    # without hardcoding the path
    code to write files to main directory (ten files )
```

Comment: What is the `main` directory? current working directory? the directory where the script reside?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to check the directory the file is operating within or check the current working directory:

```
import os
cur_dir= os.getcwd()
top_dir = os.path.dirname(cur_dir)

# perform operations in current directory
# do some stuff in top directory
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you start in the main directory, and you know the (relative) path to the subdirectories, just do

```
open(os.path.join(subdir, filename))
```

to access a path in a subdirectory without actually changing the current directory.